# c++ find() for map of member function

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, dictionary

I have two classes with inheritance. I want to allow the classes to store their function in one map. How can I create the find function by the key? And will the inheritance of the function work (MyClass_2 does not have its own doSmth() function, it should add the doSmth() from MyClass)? My attempt is below.:

```
template<class T>
class Class1
{
    typedef void(T::*MyFunction)();
    map<string, MyFunction> functionMap;
    public:
        void addFunc(string funcName, MyFunction function) {
            functionMap.insert(pair<string, MyFunction>(funcName, function));
        }

        bool findFunc(string key) {
            typename map<string, MyFunction>::iterator it;

            it = functionMap.find(key.c_str());
        }
};


class MyClass {

    Class1<MyClass> class1;

    void addFunc() {
        class1.addFunc("Func1", &MyClass::doSmth);
    }

    void findAndCallFunc(string key) {
        class1.findFunc(key);
    }

    void doSmth();

};

class MyClass_2: MyClass {

    Class1<MyClass_2> class1;

    void addFunc() {
        class1.addFunc("Func1", &MyClass_2::doSmth);
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** I tested my programm. It works. My problem is that if I call fundAndCallFunc from an object of MyClass_2. It takes not the class1 of MyClass_2, but class1 of MyClass. 
What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris says, your `findFunc` should return the actual function:

```
MyFunction findFunc(string key)
{
  const map<string, MyFunction>::const_iterator it = functionMap.find(key);
  return it == functionMap.end() ? NULL : it->second;
}
```

Further, if you only store the function pointer to a member function, you lose track of the actual object (so you could just make your map static!). Perhaps you should also store the `this` pointer of the object, i.e. make your map like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<T*, MyFunction> > functionMap;
```

In `addFunc` you would say

```
functionMap.insert(std::make_pair(funcName, std::make_pair(this, function)));
```

Usage: Suppose `it = functionMap.find("key")`. Then you could say:

```
MyClass * const p = it->second.first;
MyFunction      f = it->second.second;

p->*f();  // invoke -- yes, it's operator->*() in action
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two immediately obvious problems here:

- your `findFunc` method just looks up the function, it doesn't do anything with it (attempt to call it or return the method pointer), and its declared as returning `bool` rather than `MyFunction` -- not sure what you want it to do
- your `doSmth` method is private in MyClass, so you can't access it in MyClass_2.  You'll need to make it protected or public.